# Не работает цветной вывод в консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую библиотеку `gym`, при выполнении следующего кода:

```
import gym


if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = gym.make('Taxi-v3').env
    env.render()
```

возникает консоль со сломанным выводом цвета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

модуль colorama установлен, но это не помогает, помогите советом.

Comment: Похоже, просто консоль не поддерживает цветовые коды. Если это так, то единственный выход - использовать другую консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел проблему, все решалось вызовом `colorama.init()` в самом начале.